# Which brands of creatine are good?

Tags: weight-gain, protein, supplements, creatine

I'm skinny and want to gain some weight.
I joined a gym 3 months ago but still there is no gain.
Now I want to try creatine supplements. 
I chose two products

1. Myprotein Creatine Monohydrate
2. BULK POWDERS Creatine Monohydrate Powder, Pure and Micronised

I chose them because they are cheap.
But I don't know which one is good or which brand is good.
Please help me. Which one is good ???

And please suggest some cheap products like protein powder, carbohydrate powder, multivitamin,  fish  oil etc...  or anything which can help me.

Comment: If you'd like to gain weight, you need to increase your calories.  Supplements like Creatine, Protein powder, etc. should only be used to **supplement** your diet.  You should strive to eat good **food** on a consistent basis.

Comment: Although expensive does not necessarily mean high quality but cheap almost always means poor quality. You can look up quality rankings here: https://labdoor.com/rankings/protein and https://labdoor.com/rankings/creatine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 months is not  big enough a time for a beginner to see changes. In 3 months you hardly build 2-3 pounds of muscle mass, no matter what supplement you use, and that 2-3 pounds will be distributed all over your body, so it will hardly make any difference to human eye. To see any transformation, it will take at least a year of dedicated effort. If you stick to your schedules, eat and rest well, you'd add up 6-10 lbs(remember, it's not a linear growth) of muscle mass in a year. Not that you'd look like a competition athlete, but you can see the change. Now, if you continue, by the end of 2nd or 3rd year, you'd be able to see the real transformation when you add up to 20-25 lbs of muscle mass.

Supplements as the name suggests, are there to supplement your food intake, they are not main food sources by themselves. If you are not eating right, there's nothing much they could do. Food along with supplements, would provide you the proper benefit.

Comment: I want to get protien from foods...   and  want to use creatien supplement....   is that okey ??

Comment: When it comes to supplements, always have a word with a qualified dietician, or a doctor. Just to make sure everything is fine and you are not getting overdose of any specific nutrient. Best wishes, keep lifting.